# Issue posting variables to combo box control text value

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

I have a datagrid on a winforms app, and when the user double clicks a cell on the datagrid the following method is called.

```
private void dataCaseDiary_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int cellRow = e.RowIndex;
            int cellCol = e.ColumnIndex;
            DataTable table = (DataTable)dataCaseDiary.DataSource;
            var currentDiaryID = table.Rows[cellRow]["DiaryID"];
            var currentUser = table.Rows[cellRow]["To Action"];
            var currentType = table.Rows[cellRow]["Diary Type"];
            txtDiaryID.Text = currentDiaryID.ToString();
            cboReassign.Text = currentUser.ToString();
            cboAmendDiaryType.Text = currentType.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception eX)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(eX.Message);
        }
    }
```

However an exception occurs at the line

```
cboAmendDiaryType.Text = currentType.ToString();
```

The exception states that "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

I've spent some time looking at this, and can't find what it is I've done wrong.  The three var variables all pick up the correct values from the datagrid, two of them post to the text value of the controls on the form, but the third fails.

The prefixes I use 'txt' means text box control, and 'cbo' means combo box.

Comment: Are you sure you have column with "Diary Type" name? Maybe you need "DiaryType"?

Comment: I thought that too, but he said "The three var variables all pick up the correct values from the datagrid"
OP: Have you checked to make sure they are actually being filled?

Comment: Are you trying to set cboAmendDiaryType to a value that isn't in it's list of items?

Comment: @Anon I spotted that but you know magic string - always can mistype.:)

Comment: @PJW can you add code how you filling datagrid, if its fetched from DB add query you using?

Comment: Do you have code in events linked to your combo?. Perhaps the exception is in that code triggered when you set the combo text.

Comment: During debugging, what is the exact type of currentType? Speaking of debugging, try this: string temp = currentType.ToString(). Lastly, double check cboAmendDiary type is not null.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `table.Rows[cellRow]["Diary Type"]` don't exist and return null. I guess "Diary Type" is not correct column name.

Comment: Cannot be because "var currentType" has a value when I step through.